# Attach event to element within another function

Tags: javascript, events, parameter-passing

In my code I have a button, when clicked it shows a div. In this div, I want to have separate keyboard navigation. But when the user presses 'tab' within, the focus to go back to the button that opened it. So what I am trying to do:

```
function showMydiv(item) {

.......

$('div#myDiv').on('keydown','a', {item:item}, function(event){
......
if (event.which == 9) {
event.data.item.focus();
}
} ); 

}
```

The problem is that item is always the first clicked button. How can I make it each time I attach this handler, the item to be the button that opened the div? and is it correct to put attach event in this function, that will be called many times?

Comment: add HTML and sample data

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to detach and attach the 'keydown' event for each new item I am passing as parameter. My mistake was that I was attaching it only once.